# Vue is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My `app.js` file is like below.

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('mosque-component', require('./components/MosqueComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('prayer-component', require('./components/PrayerComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('time-component', require('./components/TimeComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
});
```

I added `app.js` file like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
<body class="footer-offset">
</body>
</html>
```

I ran `npm install`, `npm install vue` and `npm run dev`. But I am getting below error. I can't see VueJS output also.

[image]

Comment: Can you import Vue like,`import Vue from 'vue'` in `app.js` file?

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. Now I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is undefined` error. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain where are you using `default`?

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. It is imported code. I don't know why.

Comment: How are you using Vue? In a single HTML file or do you have a complete directory as we setup the Vue project?

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. I am using VueJS with Laravel. I am using `<div><time-component /></div>` like this in Laravel blade file. Thanks,.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this-

```
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
```

Use like this-

```
window.Vue = require("vue");
```

As you are using `el: '#content'`, make sure you have an element with id `content` in your blade file.

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. Now I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function` error.

Comment: Your question's error is resolved. Now, this error is some another error which seems related to laravel-mix version. Here are some discussions upon it, you might check there- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/uncaught-typeerror-vuecomponent-is-not-a-function